# Demonstrate an inequality $|(x+y+z+a^2xyz)|\ /\ |1+a^2(xy+xz+yz)|<1/a$

Tags: inequality

For $a>0, x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$

$$|x|<a,\ |y|<a, \ |z|<a$$

Demonstrate this inequality:

$$\frac{|(x+y+z+a^2xyz)|}{|1+a^2(xy+xz+yz)|}<{1\over a}$$

Comment: SOme of your formatting has gotten corrupted.

Comment: The conditions on $(x,y,z,a)$ might be that $|x|\lt1/a$, $|y|\lt1/a$, $|z|\lt1/a$. Then the inequality holds.

Comment: And the solution closely mimicks the solution provided to you on your near-duplicate question. Please read and ponder it.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality cannot be demonstrated, because there are counter-examples: For $x=1$, $y=0$, $z=0$, and all $a > 1$, we have
$$\frac{|(x+y+z+a^2xyz)|}{|1+a^2(xy+xz+yz)|} = 1 > \frac{1}{a} \cdot $$